# table tr td p h2 - what's wrong with that?

Tags: html, html-table, paragraph

Why I can't place h2 inside paragraph inside table cell? (tested on Chrome and FF)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>
                <h2>Header</h2>
                test123
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4e6Lp/

Paragraph content jumps out to the td and p becomes empty:

[image: chrome render]

Comment: @Wilf, in code he has p>h2, but in browser he has p+h2

Comment: @Epsil0neR - I noticed that, and then you posted the answer. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content model of `p` allows only “inline” or “text-level” content. The exact content model (and terminology) varies by HTML version, but no version regards `h2` as inline/text-level. See e.g. [HTML 4.01 spec text on the `p` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#edef-P). The requirement is rather natural if you think of `p` in its old meaning in HTML: it marks up a paragraph of text. It’s basically a block of copy text.

The content model is enforced by browsers, by parsing rules: when a `p` element is open, an `<h2>` tag implicitly closes it. So in the case given in the question, the `td` element contains a `p` element with just whitespace as content, then an `h2` element, and then “loose” text (just a text node).

The conclusions depend on your reasons for wanting to wrap the cell content in a `p` element. Normally, there is no reason to that. But if you need a wrapper, use the `div` element instead.

Answer (score 2):

Following to these source: http://risd.generic.cx/containment.html p element can hold only:

- TextNode
- a
- strong
- em
- img

But I think that `<p>` can hold any inline and inline-block element.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it is intentionally meant to  be a header, you can just make the text bold instead:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>
                <strong>Header</strong><br>
                test123
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Or, as @Epsil0neR says, use the `<h2>` header outside of `<p>` paragraph